# Using different colors for a logical variable on a graph in R

Tags: r, graph, graphics, ggplot2, subset

I am trying to create a graph that shows the x and y axis' but then changes the colors for whether the variable is correlated with a "T" or "F". I created a simple dataframe because the one I'm using has over 19000 variables.

```
age<- rnorm(20, 6, 2)
prediction<- rnorm(20, 17, 4)
logic<- c("T", "F", "F", "F", "T", "F", "T", "T", "T", "F", "T", "F", "F", "F", "T", "F", "T", "T", "T", "F")
data.frame(age,prediction,logic)
plot(age, prediction)
```

So, on my graph I want the points to be one color if the answer was "T" and another color if the answer was "F".

I've looked all over and tried multiple techniques with ggplot2 and subsetting but so far nothing has worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will work for `ggplot2`

```
age<- rnorm(20, 6, 2)

prediction<- rnorm(20, 17, 4)

logic<- c("T", "F", "F", "F", "T", "F", "T", "T", "T", "F", "T", "F", "F", "F", "T", "F", "T", "T", "T", "F")

df <- data.frame(age,prediction,logic) #ggplot likes data frames

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = age, y = prediction, colour = logic)) + geom_point()
```

If on the other hand, you'd like to keep this in base graphics, you can use the following to make the plot and then the legend.

```
plot(age, prediction, col = as.factor(logic))
legend("topright", c("T", "F"), col = c("black", "red"), pch = 1)
```

Comment: No problem. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.